# Is my GPU finished?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

Certain games work like WoW / Life is Strange while others do not such as Mobius FF, Unity, Parsec...

The games/applications that do not work are just a black screen, while the games that do work are utilizing the GPU just fine. In safemode the others worked, I read somewhere to disable the GPU driver which I did...and now it works (I assume it's because I am using the integrated cpus graphics card). I tried talking to nvidia support and after being with them for 4 hours they basically said "reinstall windows".

With Display adapter:

- Certain games do not work / Applications do not work
- 1920x1080 resolution

Without:

- All games work kind of? (laggy, expected)
- Base resolution (I'm guessing 800x600)

Stress testing the GPU actually works. So I'm left with this giant clunky headache of a laptop, I've been trying to fix this for 4-5 months now.

It is the ROG G751JL

I theorized something was blocking the driver from working properly so I temporarily removed almost every service/startup/application running and it did nothing, as a last attempt disabling the display driver finally gave me a result outside of safe mode. I'm still convinced something is wrong software wise as I open the games that do not work, check taskmanager and see the games ARE utilizing the gpu.

Edit: I found this utility that lets me view what applications are utilizing the GPU, and all games ARE using it. Additionally Life is Strange AND Mobius FF are both unity games which makes this conundrum even more confusing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Whoever comes by here, I had to reinstall windows, I stripped my windows hard and reinstalled/repaired/dism it many times. I had to basically start fresh to get it to work.